# Output text/link with variables inside

Tags: php

How can i make this output properly? Im using the right variables but i think im doing something wrong with quotations or what not.

```
<?php echo '<img src="' SITE_URL . 'img/' . $code '" title="Created by website.com" />' ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You  need to join **all** the pieces of the string with `.`, the concatenation operator. You're missing several.

```
<?php echo '<img src="' . SITE_URL . 'img/' . $code . '" title="Created by website.com" />' ?>
```

`echo` also accepts multiple arguments, so you may use commas instead of periods:

```
<?php echo '<img src="', SITE_URL, 'img/', $code, '" title="Created by website.com" />' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo '<img src="'. SITE_URL . 'img/' . $code .'" title="Created by website.com" />' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it multiple ways, inline with the HTML

```
<img src="<?= $SITE_URL ?>" title="..."/>
```

Or by echoing the whole string in PHP

```
<?php
    echo '<image src="' . $_SITE_URL . '" title="..."/>';
?>
```

If you do it in PHP, you need to make sure you use quotations correctly, escape characters as needed, and join all strings with a `.`